# angular custom directive inside ngif - setting its absolute son's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a custom angular directive that I conditionally display it, as it's inside ng-if. Inside my custom directive I display html elements, one of them having an absolute positioning.

I'd like to set the absolute element's width to be that of the directive's root width. Please note, I cannot set the directive root's display to be relative.

How would you advise I achieve such a feat?

**UPDATE:**
Here's a jsfiddle - 
http://jsbin.com/qofolahani/edit?html,css,js,console,output

please note that in the link function I don't yet the element's css styling yet and thus width is equal to 0, which means I cannot set it in the child div's width.

Comment: `I cannot set the directive root's display to be relative.` Why?

Comment: Because if the directive is inside a short container by itself, i'd like the absolute element to be as high as it needs without creating scrollbars in the dom

Comment: Make a fiddle, it's unclear, what you want..

Comment: Why not `son.css('width', el.css('width'))` ?

Comment: ok, I just created a js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you use `restrict: E`.
Browser does not bind `getCalculatedStyle` method to non-standard DOM entities.

Change this directive to attribute using:

```
<div my-dir></div>
```

And directive:

```
{
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function (scope, element) {
      element.addClass('my-dir');
      element.find('.my-dir-content').width(element.width());
    },
    template: '<div class="my-dir-content"></div>'
}
```

---

Or you should use internal templated divs only.
`replace: false` can help with this.

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  link : function (scope, element) {
    var o = element.find('.my-dir');
    var i = o.find('.my-dir-content');
    i.width(o.width());
  },
  replace: false,
  template: '<div class="my-dir"><div class="my-dir-content"></div>/div>'
}
```

Or otherwise, replace parent node:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  link : function (scope, element) {
    var i = element.find('.my-dir-content');
    i.width(element.width());
  },
  replace: true,
  template: '<div class="my-dir"><div class="my-dir-content"></div>/div>'
}
```

[JSBin Preview](http://output.jsbin.com/zaqubo)

---

**Bonus:**
You need a code like this to update width on window resize:

```
  $(window).on('resize', onResize);
  function onResize() {
    i.width(o.width());
  }
  scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $(window).off('resize', onResize);
  });
```

Comment: I see, yet my real directive is more complex than this. It needs to be an element. Can you think of any other workaround?

Comment: You should use internal div container then: see edit

Comment: but what if I have several levels of hierarchy inside my directive, the absolute son not being a son but more of a descendant.

Comment: [Ask new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this. With relevant fiddle

Comment: I can't seem to see the point in asking a new question, you suggested a solution, I described that it is too specific. It's in the scope of the original question

Comment: I can't to understand, why my solution is too specific. SO is not a place to give you exact code. It gives you idea. You can point any descendant node(or even any node on the page) to update it with new width. My answer just helps you to get necessary width value.

Comment: follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822352/angular-directive-setting-an-absolutely-positioned-decedents-width-to-roots

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a css style to the directive root and set this position to `relative`, something like

```
custom-directive {
   position: relative;
}
```

Setting the root html element on position: relative will allow the inner html elements to take position absolute in reference to directive.

Then you can take the inner html element and set

```
inner-html-element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I can't use relative positioning though