# Angular directive - setting an absolutely positioned decedent's width to root's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a custom angular directive with a descendant div (not a child, but somewhere down the hierarchy) that has an absolute positioning.

I'd like to set the absolute element's width to be that of the directive's root width, I attempt doing so in the directive's link function.

For various design reasons I cannot set the directive root's display to be relative.

How would you advise I achieve such a feat?

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="TestController">

<my-dir> </my-dir>  

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-dir{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

.my-dir-content{
  position:absolute;
  height:150px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

**Script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.selectOption = '2';
}]);

myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : function (scope, element) {
      var myWidth = element.width();
      var mySon = element.find('.my-dir-content');
      console.log(myWidth);
      mySon.width(myWidth);     },
        template: '<div class="my-dir">' +
    '<div class="my-dir-content"> </div>' +
    '</div>'
  };
});
```

**UPDATE:** Here's a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qofolahani/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and found that you were getting a width of "0" because the `element` parameter of the linking function is not your template `<div class="myDir">`. You need to do a `find` to get that element.

Using that, it will work. (I used width-10 so I could see it better.)

Revised directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : function (scope, element) {
      var myDir = element.find('.my-dir');
      var mySon = element.find('.my-dir-content');
      var myWidth = myDir.width();
      console.log(myWidth);
      mySon.width(myWidth-10);     
    },
    template: '<div class="my-dir">' +
        '<div class="my-dir-content"> </div>' +
        '</div>'
  };
});
```

Your old JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.selectOption = '2';
}]);

myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : function (scope, element) {
      var myWidth = element.width();
      var mySon = element.find('.my-dir-content');
      console.log(myWidth);
      mySon.width(myWidth);     },
        template: '<div class="my-dir">' +
    '<div class="my-dir-content"> </div>' +
    '</div>'
  };
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>


  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TestController">

<my-dir> </my-dir>  

</body>

</html>
```

Your CSS:

```
.my-dir{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

.my-dir-content{
  position:absolute;
  height:150px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Sorry, I didn't really get what you wanted to do.

( http://jsbin.com/miquweyufa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output )